# Creating a hexagonal map from a shapefile in R

Tags: r, mapping

I am trying to create a hexagonal grid map of the UK for a dataviz task of representing land use types. Importantly, the values I want to assign to each hexagon have nothing to do with location—I simply want to create blocks of colour that represent the share of land use overall in the UK.

A few online examples of hexbin mapping didn't quite give me what I wanted. I can get to the point where I have a regular grid of points within the UK coastline, and I can assign dummy land use types and plotting colours to that grid—but this isn't that close to the hexmap I'm looking for. stat_summary_hex and related functions produce something visually closer, but I don't want point density binning.

Example:

```
library("sf")
library("tidyverse")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
world <- ne_countries(scale = "large",country = "United Kingdom", returnclass = "sf")

### grid of points within shape:
                           
grid_spacing <- 0.3 

poly <- st_make_grid(world, square = F, what="centers", 
        cellsize = c(grid_spacing, grid_spacing*0.5)) %>%
        st_intersection(world)  %>% 
        st_sf() 

### extract points as x, y:

d<-as.data.frame(st_coordinates(poly))

#### color attribution by land use:

# dummy data

library(scales)

type<-c("agriculture","forestry", "urban", "other" )
prop<-c(0.6,0.2,0.1,0.1) # dummy data
cols<-viridis_pal()(4)

for(i in 1:length(type)){
  if(i==1){if(exists("use")){rm(use)}
    if(exists("pcol")){rm(pcol)}
  }
  ifelse(exists("use"),
         use<-c(use, rep(type[i],floor(nrow(d)*prop[i]))),  
         use<-rep(type[i],floor(nrow(d)*prop[i]))
  )
  ifelse(exists("pcol"),
         pcol<-c(pcol, rep(cols[i],floor(nrow(d)*prop[i]))),  
         pcol<-rep(cols[i],floor(nrow(d)*prop[i]))
  )
}


d<-d[1:length(use),] ## cut by rounded length

d<-data.frame(d, use, pcol)

## plot
ggplot(d, aes(x=X,y=Y, group = use))+
geom_point(pch= 23, size = 5.5, fill = alpha(pcol, 0.7), color = alpha("white", 0.7))+
  theme_void()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there: setting `st_make_grid`'s argument `square` to `FALSE` generates hexagons.

```
library("sf")
library("tidyverse")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")

UK <- ne_countries(scale = "large",
                   country = "United Kingdom",
                   returnclass = "sf") |>
  st_geometry() |> ## only geometry needed to clip the hexagonal grid
  st_transform(27700) ## reproject to British National Grid


hexgrid <- st_make_grid(UK,
               cellsize = 2e4, ## unit: metres; change as required
               what = 'polygons',
               square = FALSE ## !
               ) |>
  st_as_sf()

hexgrid_UK <- hexgrid[c(unlist(st_contains(UK, hexgrid)), 
                        unlist(st_overlaps(UK, hexgrid))) ,]
```

```
UK |> plot()
hexgrid_UK |> plot(add = TRUE)
```

[image: hexagonal grid created with st_make_grid]

From there, you can add a landuse column to your dataframe `hexgrid_UK`, set landuse values to the corresponding percentages of `nrow(hexgrid_UK)` and color by landuse.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. For anyone else reading this, it's also worth pointing out that `hexgrid_UK` will need to be sorted for contiguous plotting in colour blocks by lat or long:  `xy<-as.data.frame(st_coordinates(st_centroid(hexgrid_UK)))%>%
   add_column(rank = seq(1,nrow(hexgrid_UK), 1))%>%arrange(desc(X))` and then `hexgrid_UK<-hexgrid_UK[xy$rank,1]`.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark the answer as accepted (=close the ticket; well, if that's the case of course). For related illustrations you might also like cartograms (those thematic maps where territories are expanded/shrunk to reflect some other value than their actual geographical area; e. g. to convey a soil sealing index): https://r-graph-gallery.com/cartogram.html, https://github.com/sjewo/cartogram